# Execute procedure in select in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

My question is: how to insert from table1 to table2?

Table1 is :

```
Number Category Value
10        1      1000
10        2      5000
12        3      4000
```

Table2 is:

```
number  Category1 Category2 Category3
 10        1000      5000      NULL
 12         NULL      NULL      4000
```

I need to do that (my categories is limit).

My solution: I created a stored procedure that gets a parameter and inserts into table2, like this:

```
CREATE proc [dbo].[UpdateMemberActivityCategory]
    (@Number nchar(11),
     @Value int,
     @Type int)
AS
BEGIN
    IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM MemberActivityCategory WHERE (Number=@Number))) 
    BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO MemberActivityCategory(Number) 
        VALUES(@Number);

        IF(@Type = 2)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE MemberActivityCategory  
            SET ArtAndCulture = @Value 
            WHERE (Number = @Number)    
        END

        IF(@Type = 3)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE MemberActivityCategory  
            SET Learn = @Value 
            WHERE (Number = @Number)        
        END

        IF(@Type = 4)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE MemberActivityCategory  
            SET Business = @Value 
            WHERE (Number = @Number)        
        END
END
```

and I call that procedire like this:

```
select *, myProc(t.Number,1,t.category)
from myTable t
```

Is my solution incorrect? And what's the best way to do this?

Comment: You could look at `PIVOT`. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [a pivot table](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT * FROM (
        VALUES
            (10, 1, 1000),
            (10, 2, 5000),
            (12, 3, 4000)
        ) AS a (Number, Category, Value)
)

SELECT Number AS Number, [1], [2], [3]
FROM cte
PIVOT
(
   SUM(Value)
   FOR Category IN ([1], [2], [3])
) AS PivotTable;
```

Result:

```
10  1000    5000    NULL
12  NULL    NULL    4000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't execute a stored procedure inside a select query. Try the below query to insert the data from `table1` to `table2`.

```
INSERT INTO table2(number,  Category1, Category2, Category3)
SELECT  DISTINCT Number 
        ,(SELECT TOP 1 t1.Value FROM table1 t1 
            WHERE t1.Number = t.Number and t1.Category = 1 )
        ,(SELECT TOP 1 t1.Value FROM table1 t1 
            WHERE t1.Number = t.Number and t1.Category = 2 )
        ,(SELECT TOP 1 t1.Value FROM table1 t1 
            WHERE t1.Number = t.Number and t1.Category = 3 )
FROM    table1 t
```

Comment: thank you abdul, but i give error :"subQuery return more than 1 value. this is not permited when the subQuery follows =,!= , ..."

Comment: That means there is some duplicate table1(Number,Category). You can remove the duplicate or you can use TOP 1 in sub-query(plz check the modified answer).